# JavaScript function called only once instead of every time

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, input

I need a javascript code that checks the input file size before uploading everytime the input value changes (i.e. everytime the user selects a file to upload).

So far I came up with this:

```
var file = document.getElementById("myFile");
    file.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (this.files[0].size > 2*1024*1024) {
            alert('Max file size is 2 MB');
            file.removeAttribute('value');
            file.parentNode.replaceChild(file.cloneNode(true),file);
            }
        }
    );
```

and the **HTML** is:

```
<form action="?" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Now, if I leave the Javascript code like that, it doesn't work at all.
But if I change it like this

```
window.onload = function() {

      // Same code above

}
```

it works, but **only** for the **first file** the user selects.

How can I change it to make it work **everytime** the user selects a file? *(if possible without jQuery)*

Comment: Could you try changing it to `document.onload`?

Comment: the issue is, when the file is too big, you replace the element - it no longer has an event listener

Comment: @DustinToothless — What makes you think that would help?

Comment: @DustinToothless not working. Neither for the first file selection

Comment: just set `file.value='';` instead of the stuff you're doing

Comment: Can you even remove the `value` property?

Comment: @JaromandaX So simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to clone the node etc ... just set the value to '';

```
file.value = '';
```

see working snippet

```js
document.getElementById("myFile").addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.files[0].size > 2*1024*1024) {
    alert('Max file size is 2 MB');
    this.value='';
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="?" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation for cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

> Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values, including intrinsic (in–line) listeners. **It does not copy event listeners added using addEventListener()**

You are deleting the element with the event handler on it and replacing it with one that doesn't have a change listener

You need to call `addEventListener` again (and store `file.cloneNode(true),` in a variable so you can call `addEventListener` on it *and* pass it to `replaceChild`).

Comment: How to do what? Your code shows that you know how to use `addEventListener`, and using variables is JS 101.

Comment: @Quentin -this is the second time  today I've seen this sort of code, cloning to clear values in a form, and I've never seen this before. Is there any reason to do it this way rather than just clearing the value of the input? Genuine question, you've corrected my poor assumptions too many times to count in the past, so I do value your opinion

Comment: @JaromandaX — I probably wouldn't do it that way, but I don't know what M. C.'s reasons are.